# ClassNotFoundException when calling EJB running on weblogic 10.3 from app running on weblogic 10.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I have a stateless EJB (3.0) running on weblogic 10.3 (Java 6).

I am able to call the EJB using a standalone client without any problems (using the weblogic jars). I am using the correct jndi name.

When I try to call the EJB from an application running on weblogic 10.0 (Java 5). I get the following root exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class java.lang.Object; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject:  This error could indicate that a component was deployed on a  cluster member but not other members of that cluster. Make sure that any component deployed on a server that is part of a cluster is also deployed on all other members of that cluster]
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:74)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.translateException(WLContextImpl.java:426)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:382)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:367)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:88)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:153)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.lookup(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.getHome(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:159)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.create(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:214)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.newSessionBeanInstance(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:221)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.getSessionBeanInstance(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:141)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.doInvoke(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:97)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class java.lang.Object; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject:  This error could indicate that a component was deployed on a  cluster member but not other members of that cluster. Make sure that any component deployed on a server that is part of a cluster is also deployed on all other members of that cluster
        at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:231)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:338)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:252)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1001_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:379)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject:  This error could indicate that a component was deployed on a  cluster member but not other members of that cluster. Make sure that any component deployed on a server that is part of a cluster is also deployed on all other members of that cluster
        at weblogic.j2ee.ApplicationManager.loadClass(ApplicationManager.java:218)
        at weblogic.common.internal.ProxyClassResolver.resolveProxyClass(ProxyClassResolver.java:71)
        at weblogic.common.internal.ProxyClassResolver.resolveProxyClass(ProxyClassResolver.java:40)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:427)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream$NestedObjectInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:668)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1500)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1463)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:195)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:565)
```

**This error could indicate that a component was deployed on a  cluster member but not other members of that cluster. Make sure that any component deployed on a server that is part of a cluster is also deployed on all other members of that cluster**

This does not make sense there aren't any clusters involved (two separate weblogic instances running on my local machine).

Any idea what the cause of the exception might be?

UPDATE: If I copy wlclient.jar from weblogic 10.3 to the lib of the domain running on weblogic 10.0 the call works but that isn't a good solution and I don't understand why it has an dependency on weblogic classes.

Comment: Sounds like the `weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject` must be in another jar file in Weblogic 10 that's not in your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly this is a jar issue. Please verify all the location the classpath is referencing and make sure none of the jar files is present twice and also make sure that the jar file containing the weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObjec is present on the classpath.

Hope this helps .

Comment: I am going to accept this because adding a jar with `weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject` and `weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessHandle` to the lib of my Weblogic 10 instance. I still don't understand why this is necessary though (what would happen if I wanted to call the ejb from a different app server?). In any case it sorts out my problem for now at least.